# Python 3.5 Trying to plot PCA with sklearn and matplotlib

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, pca

Using the following code generates the error: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Pred':

I am struggling to figure out what is causing this error to be thrown.

self.features is a list composed of three floats ex. [1.1, 1.2, 1.3]
an example of self.features:

```
[array([-1.67191985,  0.1       ,  9.69981494]), array([-0.68486623,  0.05      ,  9.99085024]), array([ -1.36      ,   0.1       ,  10.44720459]), array([-2.46918915,  0.        ,  3.5483372 ]), array([-0.835     ,  0.1       ,  4.02740479])]
```

This is the method where the error is being thrown.

```
def pca(self):        
    pca = PCA(n_components=2)
    x_np = np.asarray(self.features)
    pca.fit(x_np)
    X_reduced = pca.transform(x_np)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
    plt.scatter(X_reduced[:, 0], X_reduced[:, 1], c=y, cmap='RdBu')
    plt.xlabel('First component')
    plt.ylabel('Second component')
```

The full trace back is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Post-Translational-Modification-                
Prediction/pred.py", line 244, in <module>
y.generate_pca()
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Post-Translational-Modification-
Prediction/pred.py", line 222, in generate_pca
plt.scatter(X_reduced[:, 0], X_reduced[:, 1], c=y, cmap='RdBu')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", 
line 3435, in scatter
edgecolors=edgecolors, data=data, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", 
line 1892, in inner
return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 3976, in scatter
c_array = np.asanyarray(c, dtype=float)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 583, in asanyarray
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Pred'
```

Comment: Can you please post the whole error message? Is that all code or is there some more?

Comment: Could you also post the few rows of self.features?

Comment: @2Obe Added full traceback, there is more code but it is about ~200 lines. However, I do not think it is contributing to the error.

Thank you!

Comment: @Linda I added the first 5 elements of self.features

Thank you!

Comment: What is `y` in the scatter plot? Your code works for me *as is* if I set e.g. `y = np.arange(len(features))`. I suspect your `y` is not a valid color sequence.

Comment: Try to Run only this Part of Code to Check if it draws an Error. If you have not changed anything at this Part of the code the mistake must be somwhere else

Comment: @WhoIsJack your suggestion works! Thank you! I was careless when trying to follow online tutorials and I missed `y`. The full class is called Pred and I was testing it on `y` as well which helps explain the error message. Again thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. My 'fix' was just a quick test. You could make better use of the color argument by adding more information to your plot. For example, you could use `c=x_np[:,0]` to color the dots according to the first feature, which would yield information about how that feature relates to the principal components. Alternatively, you can use e.g. `c='red'` (and remove `cmap`) to simply give all the dots the same color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested fix by @WhoIsJack is to add `np.arange(len(self.features))`

The functional code for those who run into similar issues is:

```
def generate_pca(self):
    y= np.arange(len(self.features))
    pca = PCA(n_components=2)
    x_np = np.asarray(self.features)
    pca.fit(x_np)
    X_reduced = pca.transform(x_np)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
    plt.scatter(X_reduced[:, 0], X_reduced[:, 1], c=y, cmap='RdBu')
    plt.xlabel('First component')
    plt.ylabel('Second component')
    plt.show()
```